# Customization months in jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I need to customize each month in ui datepicker. This means that for each month will show a different background image. I think to do the next:

```
<div class="calendar-container CURRENT-MONTS-CLASS"><div id="datepicker"></div></div>
```

How can I get current month name and add it as a class to datepicker's container?

Greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the month number, e.g. `.month1` - `.month12` or `.monthJanuary` - `.monthDecember` (or some other format) for this...personally I'd stick with numbers for other cultures, but you can adapt this answer for both ways.  Use the [`onChangeMonthYear` event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onChangeMonthYear) of the datepicker like this:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
   onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) { 
       //Month number (1-12) is month
       //Month name you can get by $("#datepicker .ui-datepicker-month").text()
       $(this).closest("div.calendar-container")
              .removeClass().addClass("calendar-container month" + month);
   }
});
```

And set it initially when the page loads (after creating the datepicker), since I'm using the month number in the above, it would look like this:

```
$("div.calendar-container").addClass("month" + ($('#datepicker').datepicker("getDate").getMonth()+1));
```

If you were using names instead, use:

```
$("div.calendar-container").addClass("month" + $("#datepicker .ui-datepicker-month").text());
```

Whichever option you go with, just create the 12 classes with the background images/styling you want.  [You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/uF85Y/).  If you wanted the background to actually be on the datepicker itself, not that `.calendar-container` `<div>` you'd just add that to the CSS selector to make it more specific, for example:

```
.month1 .ui-datepicker-inline { background: url(January.jpg); }
```

[You can test out that version here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/uF85Y/1/).